# Is ≤ a legit less than equals char?

Tags: javascript, operators, visual-studio-code

I was reading the release notes of Visual Studio Code and a particular caught my eye.

[image: Screenshot from the release notes]

As you can see, there is a javascript file with the ≤ symbol.
I can't figure out how it works, if I try to use it in my code I get a "Invalid or unexpected token" error (which I was expecting), and I can't find if it's only a VSCode configuration that shrinks <= into ≤ for aesthetic purposes.

How does it work?

Comment: Might be https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Comment: it IS only a VSCode configuration that shrinks <= into ≤ for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: Going to check out FiraCode, looks like it's the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a monospaced font with [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), which makes `<=` looking as one sign.

Some sources:

- https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode
- https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig
- https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka

Answer (score 2):

This is just due to the font ligature. The actual characters are 2: `<=` but the ligature renders them as one.

Some fonts support ligatures such as [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) and most likely you need to enable ligatures on your IDE if you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Ligatures for a while. These are called **Monospaced Programming Fonts with Ligatures** and it's just not [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), there are several others out there. For example -

[**Monoid**](https://github.com/larsenwork/monoid)

[image: Monoid]

---

[**Hasklig**](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig/)

[image: Hasklig]

Also these are supported by a LOT of editors and not just VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps worth to mention that for working ligatures in VSC you need:

- Locally installed font with ligatures support (Monoid / Iosevka / Fira Code)
- `editor.fontFamily` set to given font,
- `editor.fontLigatures` set to `true`.